# Как добавить один день к Date

Tags: java, android, calendar

```
Date departDate;

calendar.init(departDate, nextYear.getTime())
                    .withSelectedDate(dep);
```

У меня `departDate` может взять любую дату, то есть неизвестная у него дата, мне нужно добавить к нему один день. `departDate + 1` никак не помогает.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
Date dep1 = cal.getTime();
```

`departDate + dep1` тоже не помогает.

Как в данном случае добавить один день и вообще как добавить день к `Date`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вместо `cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);` используй метод `cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);`

Comment: Все равно ошибку выдает. Точнее не плюсует! departDate + dep получается да?

Comment: Покажи весь код, что за объект calendar, что происходит в методе init?

Answer (score 3):

Ваш код делает точно то, что вы написали, а именно добавляет один день к текущей дате, т.к. `Calendar.getInstance()` возвращает текущую дату. Если вам надо добавить что-то к определенной дате, то сначала ее необходимо установить в календарь, а потом прибавлять значение:

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
instance.setTime(date); //устанавливаем дату, с которой будет производить операции
instance.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 3);// прибавляем 3 дня к установленной дате
Date newDate = instance.getTime(); // получаем измененную дату
```